# How view mime type in Chrome? It's showing "document" under "Network" tab

Tags: html, .htaccess, google-chrome

I'm trying to determine the mime type of a file. In Firefox, it shows `text/cache-manifest`. In Chrome, `F-12 -> Network Tab` it shows under `type` as `document`. When I view the response headers, it never shows `Content-Type` so maybe my server isn't sending it? Or am I interpreting `document` wrong?

In .htaccess, I have: `AddType text/cache-manifest .manifest`

EDIT: I have also tried the below code and it still shows type as `document` in Chrome:

**manifest.php**

```
<?php header("content-type: text/cache-manifest");?>
```

Comment: Are you saying that even when you set the `Content-Type` header with `header()` you still don't see this in the HTTP response headers returned from your server?

Comment: @w3d no, when I set that, I do see it in the response headers (did not for the `.manifest` file but I do for the PHP file) but it still shows "type" as `document` on the network tab.

Answer (score 2):

Network tab filters query based on request type, not mime type. As you request it as document (simple http get request in browser, not for example from image or styles tag), then it shows it as type=document.
See https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network/reference for more info.